# Angular asynchronous data request, data array first index undefined

Tags: arrays, angular, indexing

In a function getPrognoseData() I am calling some data from http. THe log shows the data is present. However, If I continue to process the data in another function called `showFnct(0,this.dataArray)`, the log

```
console.log("Array:",nnn)
console.log("Array[0]:",nnn[0])
```

shows me that the data is undefined (or not present):

```
Array[0]: undefined
leistung.component.ts:81 Value: 0
leistung.component.ts:83 actual data: undefined
```

what am I doing wrong?

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.dataArray = this.getPrognoseData();
    console.log("Leistung Chart Daten:",this.dataArray);
    this.actualData = this.showFnct(0,this.dataArray);

  }

  showFnct(value, array) {
    var nnn = array;
    console.log("Array:",nnn)
    console.log("Array[0]:",nnn[0])
    console.log("Value:",value);
    this.actualData= array[0];
    console.log("actual data:",this.actualData);

    for (var elem of array) {
      for (var subElem of elem.series) {
        if (subElem.value > this.maxValue) {
          this.maxValue = subElem.value;
        }
        if (subElem.value < this.minValue) {
          this.minValue = subElem.value;
        }        
      }      
    }
    var range = this.maxValue - this.minValue;
    this.maxOffset = this.maxValue + range*0.1;
    this.minOffset = this.minValue - range*0.1;
    console.log("minoffset:",this.minOffset)
    console.log("Nowdata:",this.actualData);
    return this.actualData;
  }
```

Here is the implementation of getPrognoseData():

```
getPrognoseData() {
    //dummy-data
    var startTime = '2018-06-23T00:44:55';
    var endTime = '2018-09-30T14:00:55';
    var id = '123456789';
    //http://localhost:3452/edit/2018-07-23T00:44:55.2018-07-30T14:00:55.987654321
    //Builds Prognose-Daten-Graph
    this.http.get<any>(`http://localhost:5555/Demonstrator/` + id + "." + startTime + "." + endTime, {observe: 'response'}
    ).subscribe(resp => {
      if (resp.status === 200) {
        console.log("Verlauf el. Leistung: ", resp.body);
        var elLeistung = [];
        var elNFLeistung = [];
        for (var elem of resp.body) {
          elLeistung = elLeistung.concat(elem["aktElErzeugungsleistung"]);
          elNFLeistung = elNFLeistung.concat(elem.aktElNachfrageleistung);
        }
        elLeistung.sort(function(a,b){return new Date(a.Timestamp).getTime() - new Date(b.Timestamp).getTime()});
        elNFLeistung.sort(function(a,b){return new Date(a.Timestamp).getTime() - new Date(b.Timestamp).getTime()});
        console.log("elLeistung:",elLeistung);

        let aktElEZLeistung = elLeistung;//resp.body[0]["aktElErzeugungsleistung"];
        let aktElNFLeistung = elNFLeistung;//resp.body[0]["aktElNachfrageleistung"];
        let maxValue = -10000000;
        let minValue = +10000000;
        //Erzeuge NGX Chart Daten für aktuelle elekt. Erzeugungsleistung:
        //this.aktElLeistung.name = "aktElEZLeistung";
        var aktElEZLeistungDok: any = {
          name: "erzeugte Leistung",
          series: [],
        }
        for (let i = 0; i<aktElEZLeistung.length; i++) {
          this.newData = {
            name: new Date(aktElEZLeistung[i]["Timestamp"]),
            value: aktElEZLeistung[i]["Betriebswert"]
          }
          aktElEZLeistungDok.series.push(this.newData);
        }

        this.dataArray.push(aktElEZLeistungDok)

        var aktElNFLeistungDok: any= {
          name: "nachgefragte Leistung",
          series: [],
        }
        for (let i = 0; i<aktElNFLeistung.length; i++) {
          this.newData = {
            name: new Date(aktElNFLeistung[i]["Timestamp"]),
            value: aktElNFLeistung[i]["Betriebswert"]
          }
          aktElNFLeistungDok.series.push(this.newData);
        }
        this.dataArray.push(aktElNFLeistungDok)


        var aktElLeistung: any = {
          name: "elektr. Leistung",
          series: [],
        }
        for (let i = 0; i<aktElEZLeistung.length; i++) {
          this.newData = {
            name: new Date(aktElEZLeistung[i]["Timestamp"]),
            value: aktElEZLeistung[i]["Betriebswert"]-aktElNFLeistung[i]["Betriebswert"]
          }
          if (this.newData.value >= maxValue) {
            maxValue = this.newData.value;
          }
          if (this.newData.value <= minValue) {
            minValue =this.newData.value;
          }   

          aktElLeistung.series.push(this.newData);
        }
        var offset = 50;
        this.minOffset = minValue - offset;
        this.maxOffset = maxValue + offset;
        this.dataArray.push(aktElLeistung);
        this.actualData = this.dataArray;
        console.log("El Leistung:", this.dataArray);

        //Abschnitt für Fahrplanprognose Daten
        var fpdata;
        //http://localhost:5555/DNZ/FP/2018-07-23T00:44:55.2018-07-30T14:00:55.987654321
        this.http.get('http://localhost:342/'+id+'.'+startTime+'.'+endTime)
        .subscribe(
          data => { fpdata = data; console.log("FPData:",fpdata);
          var progBW: any = {
            name: "progn. Betriebswert",
            series: [],
          }
          for (let i = 0; i<fpdata.length; i++) {
            this.newData = {
              name: new Date(fpdata[i]["Timestamp"]),
              value:  fpdata[i]["PrognostizierterBetriebswert"],
            }
            progBW.series.push(this.newData);
          }
          this.dataArray.push(progBW);
          this.actualData = this.dataArray;
          console.log("DataArray elLeistung und ProgBW:", this.dataArray);
        },
          err => console.error(err)
        );

      } else {
        console.log('error bei verbindung');
      };

    });
    console.log("Data Array progBW und El Leistung:",this.dataArray);
    /this.dataArray;*/
    return this.dataArray
    }
```

to explain the last method: I am basically doing 2 http requests... and for both I am basically creating some documents {name:... series:[]} to fit the ngx charts data format based on the http data.... and pushing them into the array dataArray...

Comment: Please show the implementation of `getPrognoseData()`

Comment: ok sorry added it in edit, by the way, I am doing 2 http requests inside that method...

Answer (score 1):

This problem is that, you are not waiting for `getPrognoseData()` to return its data, before calling `this.showFnct(0,this.dataArray);`

You could return the `Observable` from `getPrognoseData()` and subscribe to it inside `OnInit()`. Once it is completed you may call `this.showFnct(0,this.dataArray);`

code :

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getPrognoseData().subscribe((data)=> {
       this.dataArray = data;
       console.log("Leistung Chart Daten:",this.dataArray);
       this.actualData = this.showFnct(0,this.dataArray);
    });
}


getPrognoseData() {
    ................
  return this.http.get<any>(`http://localhost:5555/Demonstrator/` + id + "." + startTime + "." + endTime, {observe: 'response'}
    ).switchMap(resp => {
        ..................
       return this.http.get('http://localhost:342/'+id+'.'+startTime+'.'+endTime)
        .map(
        (data) => {
          ........................
          return this.dataArray;
        },
          err => console.error(err)
        );
      .................................
    });
}
```

Comment: when I am using subscribe after the method, I am getting: ERROR TypeError: this.getPrognoseData(...).subscribe is not a function
    at LeistungComponent.push../src/app/pages/leistung/leistung.component.ts.LeistungComponent.ngOnInit (leistung.component.ts:65)

Comment: Which version of rxjs do you use? Also look there are 3 return statements. Have you made the changes accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

this is happening due to the asynchronus nature of javascript.
untill the function getPrognoseData() returns data,
the next line this.actualData = this.showFnct(0,this.dataArray); calls the function showFnct() , 
and the dataArray is not contains any value, because the getPrognoseData()still running and donot send any response.
so use promises here :

```
 this.dataArray = this.getPrognoseData().then(function(response){
     this.actualData = this.showFnct(0,this.dataArray);
});
```

and return promise from the getPrognoseData() function.

Comment: I am also getting ERROR TypeError: this.getPrognoseData(...).then is not a function
    at LeistungComponent.push../src/app/pages/leistung/leistung.component.ts.LeistungComponent.ngOnInit (leistung.component.ts:65)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:9035)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:10299)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:10261)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:10894)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:10854)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (LeistungComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1)....

Comment: To make function().then valid , u have to return promise from getPrognose function: so use deferred and $q dependency  if you are using angularJs. Btw which framework you are using , angularjs , nodejs or pure JavaScript ?